# Laravel : how to pass variable from one function to other coming from ajax call in same controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel facing issue to pass variable from one function to another function i want to pass getidvalue variable from questionquiz5 to previousbtn function?? here is my code

```
public  function questionquiz5(Request $request){
  static $startscore=0;
  static $getscore;
  static $level;
  $var = "hi";

  $getidvalue = Input::get('getid');
  $getanswervalue = Input::get('getanswer');



  $dbscore = \DB::table('5question')->select('question_id','correct_answer','question_marks','question_level')->where('question_id','=',$getidvalue)->get();

  //// some code...........


  Session::push('getscoresession',$getscore);
  Session::push('level',$level);


  $getsession = [  'qid' => $getidvalue,  'answer' => $getanswervalue];

  Session::push('answer', $getsession);

  return response()->json(['qid'=>$getidvalue,'answer'=>$getanswervalue]);   

  return $this->previousbtn( $getidvalue);
  return $this->previousbtn( $getanswervalue);
}     


**previousbtn function:**


public function previousbtn(Request $request, $getidvalue)
{
  $prevbtnvalue = Input::get('page');  
  $getcompid = $this->getidvalue;
  echo "$getcompid";     
}
```

**the error:**

> getting error : Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\scorecontroller::previousbtn(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Comment: please fix your question. format and wording.

Comment: You are not passing proper Arguments. And I see that you didn't use the passing argument in the function.

Comment: i know i am not able to understand how to pass can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

Like the error indicates, you are passing too few arugments.

```
return $this->previousbtn( $getidvalue);
```

Should be

```
return $this->previousbtn($request, $getidvalue);
```

Or if the request object is not used in the `previousbtn` method you can remove it from the arguments.

Comment: not working still getting error :message
:
"Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\scorecontroller::previousbtn(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"
trace
:
[{function: "previousbtn", class: "App\Http\Controllers\scorecontroller", type: "->"},…]

Comment: There is something you're not sharing, `questionquiz5` should never even get to the `previousbtn` calls since it's returned on line above it, besides this is a different message.

Comment: Do you call that function somewhere in routes? Because that is where there would be 1 parameter expected, if you call it manually, there would be 2 parameters expected (as seen above in your original question). So basically this answer eliminated 1 error, but the other one is still there :O